# Sending release to NIL in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, macos, memory-management, null

can someone explain to me the output of this program in a mac computer and then on an iphone device.

I create a trivial Foo class which contain nothing, Foo.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Foo : NSObject {

}

@end
```

and the Foo.m :

```
#import "Foo.h"

@implementation Foo

@end
```

To testing this on a Mac, i use this main.m :

```
#import "Foo.h"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Foo *myFoo; 

    [myFoo description];
    printf("%p\n", myFoo);
    [myFoo release];

    [pool drain];

    return 0;
}
```

This program output :

```
0x0
```

But on an iphone it crashes directly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You're not sending release to a nil variable. Just as in C,

```
Foo *myFoo;
```

creates an uninitialized stack variable, which can contain any garbage value. On your Mac, it is presumably happening to have the value 0 (nil), while on the iPhone it is happening to have some other value that results in a crash.

Comment: Sorry, but it's on the heap not the stack!

Comment: No, you get it wrong, Gallois. `Foo*x` is a pointer *on* a stack, which points usually *to* the heap. So, the value of `x` itself (not the object pointed to) is not initialized.

Comment: Ok thanks Yuji, and what about sending release to an nil object? and why it crash on iphone not on the mac.

Comment: @Gallois: It doesn't crash on your Mac because the random stack garbage just happens to be nil there. In other words, you just get lucky.

Comment: Why i'm luck on the Mac and not on the iPhone?

Comment: Who knows? Maybe next time you won't be. Maybe it will crash on your Mac tomorrow, but not on your iPhone. That's why it's called luck.

Comment: You probably have way more memory to get "lucky" with on your Mac

Comment: If you want to know why this particular implementation detail magically works on a Mac (because, in this case, it is magic that it works)but not on an iPhone, you should disassemble the function for both architectures and see why the register that holds the first argument to the call happens to be zero on the mac, but not on the iPhone.  An interesting exercise, but -- ultimately -- not something you should ever rely upon.

Comment: Doesn't OS X automatically zero out deallocated memory?

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C, when you call a method on a nil pointer, nothing happens.

But, in your code above, you do not set the pointer to nil, so you are sending a message to a memory location.  If you application does not have access to that memory location it will crash with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS message.

Adding this should stop if from crashing: `Foo *myFoo = nil;`

Comment: Sorry but it run fine on a mac, not on an iphone, you can test it.

Comment: @Gallois: Whether or not it works if your app is built for mac is irrelevant.  The main point is you should just set your pointers to nil so you can be sure they are not pointing to some random memory location.

Comment: Even if it **happens** to run fine on your Mac, the fact that it does so is just a happy accident, not something you can rely upon. As the saying goes, even a broken clock is right twice a day.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line here is that this line:

```
Foo *myFoo;
```

The above does **not** create an instance of Foo. All it does is declare a variable that can, if you create and initialize such an instance, be used to refer to it. To declare the variable **and** create the instance, you need to do this:

```
Foo *myFoo = [[Foo alloc] init];
```

Additionally, this line:

```
[myFoo description];
```

That does nothing at all. The -description method returns a string, but you're not storing the returned string anywhere, or doing anything else with it.

I could go on, but I won't - my advice to you is to go to Apple's site and read their [Learning Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html) tutorial, as well as the additional articles linked from there. Doing that will be a far more effective way to learn the language than just making stuff up and expecting the compiler to understand it.